# Turn by turn navigation iOS app using MapKit

Tags: ios

I am developing an **iOS** app. It can provide turn by turn navigation. With **MKDirectionsRequest**, code can get navigation routes from device's current location to the destination. **CoreLocation** updates the device current location coordinates.

1. How can I check if the device follows the direction routes after the device starts to move?
2. Any API can change viewing map perspective from top view to street view in MKMapView?

Normal GPS provides this feature when the driver drives to local after off the highway.